# How to delete the columns of a dataframe that have only positive values in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm working with Julia and trying to edit a DataFrame.
My objective is to keep the columns in which at least one value is <=0.

For example, using the code

```
using DataFrames

data = Dict("A"=>[1,7,2], 
    "B"=>[3,-9,-3], 
    "C"=>[3,0,6], 
    "D"=>[8,4,2], 
    "E"=>[4,3,-4])

df = DataFrame(data)
```

I get the following result

[image]

And I'm trying to transform it into the following DataFrame

[image]

There are some options to remove rows based on conditions, but I haven't found any that does the same to columns.

Does anyone know how to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to do this as DataFrames offers the full flexibility of Julia base, but a simple and in my opinion clear way is:

```
julia> data[!, any.(<=(0), eachcol(data))]
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ B      E     
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     3      4
   2 │    -9      3
   3 │    -3     -4
```

Let me also add that you don't have to create a `Dict` to create a `DataFrame`, the constructor works fine with `String` / `Vector` pairs:

```
julia> data = DataFrame("A"=>[1,7,2], 
           "B"=>[3,-9,-3], 
           "C"=>[3,0,6], 
           "D"=>[8,4,2], 
           "E"=>[4,3,-4])
3×5 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C      D      E     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼───────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1      3      3      8      4
   2 │     7     -9      0      4      3
   3 │     2     -3      6      2     -4
```

Comment: Minor remark, he asked for <=0 not <0. Works just as well of course.

Comment: Great. However, you should also update the output accordingly :) Currently it doesn't match the desired output in the OP (column C is missing).

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much for the quick and effective response!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it,

```
using DataFrames
data = DataFrame(A = [1, 7, 2], B = [3, -9, -3], C = [3, 0, 6], D = [8, 4, 2], E = [4, 3, -4])
```

With array comprehension

```
data[!, [ any(x -> x ≤ 0, col) for col in eachcol(data) ]]
```

or with `map`

```
data[!, map(col -> any(x -> x ≤ 0, col), eachcol(data))]
```

or with broadcasting as in Nils' answer

```
data[!, any.(≤(0), eachcol(data))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit janky, but you can find whether each element is <= 0 and then find the maximum value within each column to find cols that contain such an element. From there, you can filter by standard indexing:

```
julia> relevant_cols = maximum.(eachcol(df .<= 0))
5-element BitArray{1}:
 0
 1
 1
 0
 1

julia> reduced_df = df[!,relevant_cols]
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ B     │ C     │ E     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 3     │ 3     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ -9    │ 0     │ 3     │
│ 3   │ -3    │ 6     │ -4    │
```

EDIT: Made the answer compatible with current versions of `DataFrames` and removed previously suggested `filter!` command as a potential solution, as it's row-based not column-based.

Comment: Which DataFrames version are you on? Indexing a DataFrame with a single index has not been supported for a while, DataFrames are 2-dimensional objects so for consistency with Julia base indexing has to work by `df[rowindex, colindex]`. Your solution errors on the current release. Also `filter!` is a row-wise concept so won't help in this case.

Comment: I'm using `v0.21.8`, which means that I'm in a major need of an upgrade. Oops! Yeah, I was just cross checking `filter!` functionality, and it is indeed row-wise.